# No matching function for call to error. Pushing a string into a vector

Tags: c++

Getting error:

proj08-struct.cpp: In constructor ‘Image::Image(std::__cxx11::string)’:
proj08-struct.cpp:41:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector >::push_back(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, char>::value_type&)’
v_.push_back(line[j]);//adds row to vector

```
 Image::Image (string f_name){
   ifstream objfile(f_name);//creates object file
   string line;//each line/row in matrix 
   vector<vector<long>> v_;
   istringstream iss;
   long height_,width_,max_val_;
    int counter=0;
   do{
       getline(objfile,line);//goes through each line in objfile
   }//of do
       while(line[0]!='#'||line[0]!='P');//skip when the line starts with a # or P
            if(counter==0){
                iss>>height_>>width_;
                counter++;
            }//of if
            else if(counter==1){
                iss>>max_val_;
                counter++;
            }//of first else if
            else if(counter<1){
                for(int i=0; i<height_; i++){//goes to next row
                    for(int j=0; j<width_; j++){//goes through row
                        v_.push_back(line[j]);//adds row to vector
                    counter++;
                    }//of inside for 
                }//outside for
            }//of second else if

    //cout<<v_<<endl;
}//of Image contructor
```

This is supposed to read a PGM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PGM_example) and skip the lines starting with # or P and read the line after those lines as the height and width. Then read the next line and store it as the max value. Then read the rest of the lines and push all of those numbers (after the max value) into a vector (v_).

Comment: Looks you have defined your vector as vector of long and trying to insert string into vector.

Comment: Thank you! How could I push the numbers from line into a vector of vector<long>? I'm supposed to use that type for my project which is why I kept it, but feel stuck now.

Comment: If you are required to extract only integer values from each line, i suggest you to read the line word by word and check if the word is numeric value and then if its numeric, then insert it into your vector.

Answer (score 0):

You vector declaration is wrong. You are declaring `vector<vector<long>> v_` and trying to insert a string into `v_`

`vector<vector<long>> v_` this means v_ is a vector which has `vector<long>` type at each index position on v_. You need to change your v_ declaration to `vector<string> v_` if you want to store the text read line by line in a vector each line at an index position in vector.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to figure out a way to push each character in the line to a vector representing the data on a line and then push that vector to another vector, representing the data in the whole file. This can be achieved like this:

```
Image::Image (string f_name)
{
    ifstream objfile(f_name);
    string line;
    vector<vector<long>> v_;
    strstream iss;
    long height_, width_;
    int counter = 0;

    while( !objfile.eof() ) {
        string line;
        string junk;
        getline(objfile, line);
        if (line[0] != '#' && line[0] != 'P' && line[0]) {
            strstream iss;
            iss << line;
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                iss >> width_ >> height_;
            }
            else {
                vector<long> l;
                for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                {
                    long temp = 0;
                    iss >> temp;    
                    l.push_back(temp);
                }
                v_.push_back(l);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height_; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width_; j++)
        {
            std::cout << v_.at(i).at(j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```